# Materialized view to use different Serde

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka-streams

Version used:  Kafka 3.1.1, Confluent 7.1.0, Avro 1.11.0

I’m creating a REST controller which is “searching” for AVRO objects in a topic. The objects in the topic are serialized using SpecificAvroSerde<>. Each topic has assigned two AVRO schemas. One for the key (with several fields of various types) and one for the value (multiple fields and types).

I’ve done this several times whereby I’m consuming the topic in a KTable and then materialize it. There is only one pair of serdes involved and the serialized format is the same for both the topic and the materialized view (RocksaltDb). The REST controller then can look up the store and either perform a get with a key or do a range scan between two keys. This all works as expected.

```java
private final static String TOPIC_NAME = "input-topic";
private final static String VIEW_NAME = "materialized-view";

private final SpecificAvroSerde<ProductXrefKey> productXrefKeySerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
private final SpecificAvroSerde<ProductXref> productXrefSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();

final Map<String, Object> props = this.kafkaProperties.buildStreamsProperties();

productXrefKeySerde.configure(props, true);
productXrefSerde.configure(props, false);
KTable<ProductXrefKey, ProductXref> productXrefTable = builder
        .table(TOPIC_NAME, Consumed.with(productXrefKeySerde, productXrefSerde),
                Materialized.<ProductXrefKey, ProductXref, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(VIEW_NAME)
                        .withKeySerde(productXrefKeySerde)
                        .withValueSerde(productXrefSerde));

<…>

final ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<ProductXrefKey, ProductXref> store =
        streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams().store(fromNameAndType(VIEW_NAME, keyValueStore()));

try (KeyValueIterator<ProductXrefKey, ProductXref> range = store.range(fromKey, toKey)) {
  if (range != null) {
    range.forEachRemaining(kv -> {
    <…>
    });
  } else {
    log.info("Could not find {} in local ReadOnlyKeyValueStore {}", fromKey, viewName);
  }
}
```

I now want to change this using a prefix scan instead. Since the key contains multiple fields there is no way to only serialize first part (i.e. first few fields) of the key I need a specialized serializer. This also means I have to use a different serializer for the materialized view itself (SpecificAvroSerde puts the magic number and schema ID at the beginning of the byte array) as otherwise the serialized output for the prefix and the key in the materialized view can’t be compared. Hence I created a specialised Serde which serializes the key using the same logic as when used for serializing the prefix but omitting the fields not required for the scan (i.e. omitting the last field). Above code now looks

```java
private final static String TOPIC_NAME = "input-topic";
private final static String VIEW_NAME = "materialized-view";

private final SpecificAvroSerde<ProductXrefKey> productXrefKeySerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
private final SpecificAvroSerde<ProductXref> productXrefSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();

private final SpecificAvroSerde<ProductXrefKey> materializedProductXrefKeySerde = new ProductXrefKeySerde();
// for the value part we can still used standard serde as no change in serialization logic needed
private final SpecificAvroSerde<ProductXref> materializedProductXrefSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();

// telling the serializer to cut off last field 
private final SpecificAvroSerde<ProductXref> prefixScanProductXrefSerde = new ProductXrefKeySerde(true);

final Map<String, Object> props = this.kafkaProperties.buildStreamsProperties();

productXrefKeySerde.configure(props, true);
productXrefSerde.configure(props, false);
KTable<ProductXrefKey, ProductXref> productXrefTable = builder
        .table(TOPIC_NAME, Consumed.with(productXrefKeySerde, productXrefSerde),
                Materialized.<ProductXrefKey, ProductXref, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(VIEW_NAME)
                        .withKeySerde(materializedProductXrefKeySerde)
                        .withValueSerde(materializedProductXrefSerde));

<…>

final ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<ProductXrefKey, ProductXref> store =
        streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams().store(fromNameAndType(VIEW_NAME, keyValueStore()));

try (KeyValueIterator<ProductXrefKey, ProductXref> range = store.prefixScan(prefixKey, prefixScanProductXrefSerde)){
  if (range != null) {
    range.forEachRemaining(kv -> {
    <…>
    });
  } else {
    log.info("Could not find {} in local ReadOnlyKeyValueStore {}", prefixKey, viewName);
  }
}
```

My assumption was, that the topic gets deserialized using the SpecificAvroSerde and then gets serialized for the view using my ProductXrefKeySerde.  The problem is, that the content in the materialized view is still serialized using the same logic as in the original topic. It appears that the serializer is never used during the topic being processed and stored in the materialized view. I can verify that also on the file system and see that the keys in the RocksaltDb files are serialized with the magic byte and schema ID and hence prefixScan wont be able to fine anything.

How can I change the serialization format for the materialized view?
Or is there a better way for serializing a prefix AVRO object?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is some optimization happening which avoids deserialization/serialization if KTable is directly materialized. I've changed the logic such that it consumes it as a KStream and then creates the KTable (`toTable(...)`)

```
KTable<ProductXrefKey, ProductXref> productXrefStream = builder
            .stream(TOPIC_NAME, Consumed.with(productXrefKeySerde, productXrefSerde))
                    .toTable(Materialized.<ProductXrefKey, ProductXref, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(VIEW_NAME)
                            .withKeySerde(productXrefKeySerde)
                            .withValueSerde(productXrefSerde));
```

With this small change, data now gets deserialized (using SpecificAvroSerde<>) and serialized again using the provided ProductXrefKeySerde. Now also the prefix scan works and returns the records as expected.